# Meteor.loginWithFacebook is failing

Tags: facebook-graph-api, meteor, facebook-javascript-sdk

I keep getting this error message while trying to implement the Meteor.loginWithFacebook() method.  Login used to work for my app now it doesn't anymore and I have no idea why:

[image]

I have it set so when the facebook login button is clicked, the Meteor.loginWithFacebook() method is called, like so (client-side):

```
'click .facebook-login':function(event){
    Meteor.loginWithFacebook({requestPermissions:['user_photos', 'user_videos'], loginStyle:"popup"},function(err){
        if (err)
            throw new Meteor.Error(err, "Facebook Login Failed");
    });
}
```

Server-side:

```
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.upsert(
  { service: "facebook" },
  {
    $set:{
      // Development
      appId: "App-ID-String",
      secret: "App-Secret-String"
    }
  }
);
```

Oddly enough, this works fine when working in development but when I push my code to my production server, I get the error above.  This code also worked for several months and then just stopped working, in production.  I've cleared both databases to start from scratch and I still get the error in production but not development.

Before you mention it, I have separate code blocks to handle the different appId and secret based on development versus production, but the code is essentially the same and accounts for both environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the Facebook SDK is particular about your URL prefix/host (if there is or is not a 'www' in front of your URL) and treats the URLs as separate sites.  When going to my site to login, the non-www prefixed URL version of my site could not login to Facebook but the 'www' one could.

I was able to fix this by forcing my app to reload the 'www' prefixed URL if the non-www URL was accessed using the following code.  I tried forwarding using the GoDaddy DNS interface but it didn't work.

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  if (location.host.indexOf('www') === -1) {
    location = 'http://www.example.com';
  }
});
```

This instantly fixed my primary issue though it seems this isn't the most ideal way of handling this since it basically loads the application twice if the user visits the non-www URL.